# SharePoint 2010 Online -- Change status of all parallel tasks on Rejection of any task

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, workflow

I have a workflow which assigns tasks to users parallely. My requirement is:

1. If more than one user is assigned a task and any of the users reject the activity, it should change the status of all the tasks to Completed.

What is happening:

When one user rejects the task the status of other tasks for the same item is " Not Started ".

Why I want it to change:

My reminder workflows set up send reminder emails based on the status field. So if one user rejects the task the other one does not act on their task and the status remains as " Not Started " and reminders are sent to the user.

Thanks!